# How to prove that $\Bbb C[X,Y]/(XY) \ncong \Bbb C[X,Y]/(X) \times \Bbb C[X,Y]/(Y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-homomorphism

How to prove that $\Bbb C[X,Y]/(XY) \ncong \Bbb C[X,Y]/(X) \times \Bbb C[X,Y]/(Y)$ .

I have no idea about this problem on how to proceed, so I couldn't make any attempt.

Comment: Does * denote the Cartesian product?

Comment: Yes * denotes cartesian product

Comment: Are you confused about what the question is asking or is it just that you can’t figure out how to start?

Comment: I understand the Question but can't solve it

Comment: @Mustafa, $\mathbb C[X] \times \mathbb C[Y]$ is *not* an integral domain.

Comment: In fact, do you want to show that they are not isomorphic as rings? Or do you only want to show that the natural map $\mathbb C[X,Y]/(XY) \to \mathbb C[X,Y]/(X) \times \mathbb C[X,Y]/(Y)$ is not an isomorphism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mathbb C[X,Y]/(XY)$ had a nontrivial idempotent, then there would exist polynomials $P(X)$, $Q(Y)$ with $$XY \mid (P(X)+Q(Y))^2 - (P(X)+Q(Y))$$
and $P(X)+Q(Y) \neq 0,1$. Looking at the highest degree coefficients, we get a contradiction.